# Android navigation drawer custom listview

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I'm trying the new navigation drawer UI from google.
I read the google's sample app, but i want to add icons to listview.

Each item in list --> icon + title

Any recommendations?

Comment: You might use a custom row which is a simple TextView. As you might know, TextViews can contain drawables (not only icons, also xml drawables) inside, at the four sides (these are called compound drawables).